# Packaging Inno Setup installer with Chocolatey

Tags: windows, inno-setup, chocolatey

One of the outputs of my current build process is an Inno Setup exe installer. Is there a standard way to package Inno Setup installers for distribution with Chocolatey? Is this a good idea?

I tried to use `choco new mypackage`, but I'm not sure whether the `Install-ChocolateyInstallPackage` command in the default template is what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like what you are wanting to do is to create an embedded package, where you put the exe within the nupkg file.  With that in place, you would then use the `Install-ChocolateyInstallPackage` command to execute the installer, passing in the required silent arguments, etc. to make it work.

The difference between the `Install-ChocolateyInstallPackage` and the `Install-ChocolateyPackage` cmdlets is that the latter expects a URL to an installer that it will first download the file from and install it.  The former expects a path to where the installer resides, and goes from there.

The `choco new` command is quite verbose, as it is trying to cover all the options for what you "can" put into a Chocolatey package. You can start trimming it down to only the things that are required by the `Install-ChocolateyInstallPackage` cmdlet.

Comment: thank you! yes, trimming down is a good idea. got a bit confused by all the options